# 3rd party LINQ to SQL / EF designer search features add-on

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

I am searching for this feature: To search for an entity, relation ... etc in the designer. In EF designer the model browser window make finding entities a little easier but in LINQ to SQL there is no such thing. Also searching in the designer area is not available at all. I am wondering if I am the only one who sees this a s requirement? Viewing the model in the designer makes it more easier to discover/view relations... etc.
Anyway is there any way or 3rd party tool which makes search for entities, items in the model possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Entity Developer](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/download.html).
We offer the functionality you have requested.

Comment: Is there a Visual studio add-on for Entity Developer?

Comment: You can just select Add New Item -> Devart LINQ to SQL Model and  Entity Developer will be launched.
When the model is saved the code generation is applied automatically, and the model and code are added to your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find them by name, just use the dropdown in the property dialog in VS. When you select an entity or association in the property dialog, that entity or association will become selected in the L2S designer and will be scrolled into view.

Comment: This will not work if you have huge number of items in the designer. I want a search feature where you type keyword and then navigate within the results

Answer (score 0):

I created a VS2008 AddIns to provide a search facility for Linq-To-Sql and Entity Framework Designer. It's now available in CodePlex.

[OrmAddIns](http://ormaddins.codeplex.com/)